# Load elements to fill screen based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, viewport

I'm looking for a way to fill the viewport with elements based on the viewport size.

Is there a way to use methods like `createElement()` and `load()` to do this?

Specifically, I'm trying to fill the viewport with small circle divs. The way I have it set up now, is to just manually code them all into the html and set overflow to hidden, so that the divs beyond the screen size aren't visible.

If this isn't possible, is there a way to tell the JS I'm running to animate only those divs which are visible?

I have a codepen with the divs set up here as a reference for what I'm talking about. At full screen size, you can see that there are divs missing from the bottom of the page.

Comment: See what, where's the pen ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/a6ftcruton/pen/coDIx

It was in there, I swear!

Comment: Your green is yellow...